# You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the "framework.test" config is not set to true

Tags: symfony, phpunit, symfony4

i am trying to apply functional test using WebTestCase.

```
class CalculatorControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSumPost()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $client->request('GET', '/calculator/sum');

        $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I have the following error message when i run test:

```
 You cannot create the client used in functional tests if the "framework.test" config is not set to true
```

My test framework:

```
framework:
 test: ~
 session:
   storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
 router:
   resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_test.yml"
  profiler:
   collect: false
```

My phpunit.xml: (i tries also test instead of dev in APP_ENV & Debug 1 instead of 0)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit
    backupGlobals               = "false"
    backupStaticAttributes      = "false"
    colors                      = "true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions   = "true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions  = "true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions = "true"
    processIsolation            = "false"
    stopOnFailure               = "false"
    bootstrap                   = "config/bootstrap.php" >

<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="AppKernel" />
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="dev" />
    <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="0" />
    <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
    <!-- define your env variables for the test env here -->
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Plein Test Suite">
        <directory>tests/unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I took a look of all relative issues but i can not find a good answer, any ideas please?

Comment: In your `config/packages/test/framework.yaml` you have `test: ~`, but I guess it should be `test: true`. See: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.2/config/packages/test/framework.yaml#L2

Comment: Thanks but also when i set hem to true and restart docker container is not working

Comment: You might need to rebuild the caches. Have you tried `php bin/console cache:clear --env=test` or alternatively `rm -rf var/cache/test*`

Comment: Assuming you are using a relatively standard Symfony installation, replace `<env name="APP_ENV" value="dev" />` to `<env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />` in your `phpunit.xml` file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the following to my `phpunit.xml.dist` / `phpunit.xml` file (inside the `phpunit` tag):

```xml
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true"/>
</php>
```

Comment: This was the fix that worked for me while updating to Symfony 5.3.13. The update of the recipe "symfony/framework-bundle" introduced value="dev".

Comment: force="true" helps me on Symfony6, but it work without it on Symfony5

Comment: force="true" also for Symfony 3 and phpUnit 8

Comment: force=true has to be used in 5.1 as well, this solved my problem